# how to trigger a jenkins multibranch job using comment a pull request with Post Webhooks for Bitbucket plugin

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Post Webhooks for Bitbucket plugin to trigger pull request event.
I enabled below options:
    "Pull request created"
    "Pull request re-scoped"
It works find when I create a push request.
A new requirement is I wish when comment a pull request with specified info like "run this again", to trigger the jobs run, I've seen these is option:
    "Pull request commented"
but I don't know how to use it.
I searched but didn't find any useful docs.
Anyone can help to give a link or an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two solutions to this.

**Solution 1**

1. Use the [webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/managing-webhooks-in-bitbucket-server-938025878.html) that comes with Bitbucket Server. I think it was introduced in Bitbucket Server 5.4.
2. Use [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/) in Jenkins to consume the webhook JSON. This plugin is documented on how to create filters with regexp to only trigger for some specific conditions.

**Soltuion 2**

1. Use [Pull Request Notifier for Bitbucket Server](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213177/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket) plugin in Bitbucket Server. To trigger Jenkins.
2. Create an ordinary, no plugins needed, parameterized job in Jenkins and trigger it with the Bitbucket Server plugin.